Function to read a directory's files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each file. However nobs remain constant
I am trying my assignment from coursera and the instruction is to read the files from the directory and report on the number of completely observed cases in each file. However, my nobs remain constant.
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
  mdata <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  nobs <- numeric()
  for (i in id) {
    nobs <- sum(complete.cases(mdata))
  }
  return(data.frame(id, nobs))
}

This was the response:
complete('Specdata', 1:10)
   id nobs
1   1  333
2   2  333
3   3  333
4   4  333
5   5  333
6   6  333
7   7  333
8   8  333
9   9  333
10 10  333

However, I was expecting a response like:
complete("specdata", 30:25)
##   id nobs
## 1 30  932
## 2 29  711
## 3 28  475
## 4 27  338
## 5 26  586
## 6 25  463


You are not reading the contents of the files, only iterating over the vector of their names.
Let's go step by step:
1.
mdata <- list.files(directory, full.names = T)

mdata now holds a vector with the names of all the files inside directory (presumably, 333 files).
2.
nobs <- numeric()

nobs is now an empty vector (i.e. with length=0).
3.
Now let's look at the loop:
for(i in id) {
  nobs <- sum(complete.cases(mdata))
}

Note two things: you aren't using i anywhere inside the loop, so you are merely repeating the nobs <- sum(complete.cases(mdata)) 332 times.  Also, since mdata is merely a vctor of names, and since none of them is a missing value, complete.cases will always return the number of files inside the directory (well, the number of names, to be more accurate).  So in this loops you are writing 333 into nobs over and over again.
4.
You final line with then create a data.frame with the same value in nobs for every id:
return(data.frame(id, nobs))


You need to add a step inside the for loop to read the appropriate file into a data.frame, and then run complete.cases on that data.frame.

+1 for explaining the problem without providing the solution. I think that’s the best way to  answer homework questions.

Thanks for your guidance. I have been able to fix the problem now.

Just two quick notes on for loops, since @ZéLoff already helped you to find a solution.

I see you doing nobs <- numeric() which produces numeric vector
nobs of length(nobs) == 0. It is much more efficient in terms of
memory allocation and computing time to initialize nobs already
with its known length.
You are also doing for (i in id) which fails if id was empty,
i.e. of length(id) == 0. seq_along(id) and seq_len(length(id))
are safer: they correctly skip empty vectors, while 1:n wrongly
would loop twice for them.

For example, consider vector val,
> val <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

Instead of doing,
> res1 <- numeric()
> for (v in val) {
+   res1 <- c(res1, v)
+ }
> res1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

better do
> res2 <- numeric(length=length(val))  ## initialize with known length
> for (i in seq_along(val)) {  ## loop over a sequence...
+   res2[[i]] <- val[[i]]  ## ... and use `i` for indexing
+ }
> res2
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

I provided a small benchmark in this answer.

+1. I'll just add that IMHO for loops often are the wrong solution in R. In this case I'd go with sapply (which are safe for zero-length ids, incidentally), avoids the inefficiency of recursive concatenation and doesn't leave residue (the i object). But since this is an "homework" assignment, going that route would be off-topic.

@ZéLoff With "wrong", you probably mean, they often are considered not an "efficient solution". This not entirely true, actually in some cases they can be much more efficient than lapply, here an example.

That's why I said "often", and not "always" :) And yes, "wrong" might have been too strong.
